# why is Bot Emulator v4 - Refresh access token failed with code 400?

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service, direct-line-botframework

I am using

Ver 4.1.0 Bot emulator

When I tried to use the production endpoint in the bot framework emulator. I have configured the endpoints in the bot file as below with information from the azure. But I am unable to the access it via the Emulator and also it does not connect in the "Test in Webchat" in Azure after deployment via Git to Azure. It works fine locally

It returns the following error

[image]

In the channels I see the following error triggered. 
[image]

I analyzed the issue using Fiddler Trace. I think the tokens are being generated.

[image]

But the Emulator is not picking it. As seen in the below screenshot both of the fiddler and emulator refers to the same conversation ID.
[image]

what might be the issue that is triggering token failure?

Answer (score 1):

I think the bot service is down at the moment.

Comment: I have no clue. It has happened 5 months back when there was a global issue with gateway timeout from Microsoft bot framework there was no notification from Azure. I think the same issue is repeating again.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4738#issuecomment-435190450 there may be something wrong at the moment

Comment: Thanks @NicolasR  for the information. But i am still facing this issue.

Comment: @deepan - Can you try again now?

Comment: I have case when I switch to another Azure app(appId) this an error disappeared